# getting a connection was reset error on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, httpruntime

I'm am try trying to upload Video and audio file on live website. the example: domain.com/admin/fileupload.aspx that was a url. I use this code in web.config this :

`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="1048576" />`

with this web.config setting i didn't get The error connection was reset error on run time that is working on localhost:port/domainfolder/admin/fileupload.aspx very well. 
but that is not working on live domain. i also try this in live web.confg setting that is

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

but this is not working and getting same error. please help me out how can i solve this problem. I want to upload big files on web site ever video and audio file size around 60MB to 5GB around please let me know how can i fix this error connection was reset on live website.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not giving an answer here. But the upload speed would depend on your net connection Upload Speed. Incase of localhost it would be using the 8080 port hence much faster.

Comment: okay so that was right code which i wright in web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS7 then there is a built in limit in IIS of 30MB (request-filtering feature)
You can change it by running the following command

```
appcmd set config "My Site/MyApp" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:1073741824 -commitpath:apphost
```

(set to about 1GB)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754791(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754791%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I didn't get you exactly where i want to do this change.