# Active Report 6 not working in Windows 10

Tags: activereports

I am using Active Report 6. Recently i updated my windows 8.1 to Win 10. 
After that i can work on Active Reports through visual studio. 
But I am not able to view report by running the application. 
It keeps saying loading and then the message "The connection was reset".

Comment: After another Windows 10 update, my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is related with ActiveReports. 
In case, you are using a Web Project, this might be ASP .Net related issue. Please check following links discussing the same:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/291266/The-connection-was-reset-after-clicking-on-a-butto
[getting a connection was reset error on asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607082/getting-a-connection-was-reset-error-on-asp-net)

Anyhow, ActiveReports 6 surely not supported on Windows 10. Hence, for using AR on Windows 10, you need to update the ActiveReports version to AR9 or AR10:
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#Requirements.html